# opengl tutorial in Cloud infrastructure

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, visual-c++

I need help with the OpenGL tutorial (https://learnopengl.com/) in visual studio, but my computer has crashed and what I am currently using does not support it. I wonder if there is any way to run it (the tutorial) in the cloud or something?

Comment: Can't you just reinstall your computer? Or grab yourself a Linux live CD / USB and boot and work from there?

Comment: unfortunately not, but thank you.